# How to remove files and folders underneath a specific folder

Tags: linux, find, rm

As we know, to remove files we can use this safe option

```
  find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

What if we want to remove both folders and files under  /path/to/directory/ folder; what should be the syntax?

The delete option can't remove folders that are not empty.

```
 find /var/tmp -type d -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
 find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option    argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests   specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify  options before other arguments.

 find: cannot delete `/var/tmp/foreman-ssh-cmd-1b987fef-10ca-4204-bf4b-441f28a3db07': Directory not empty
 find: cannot delete `/var/tmp/foreman-ssh-cmd-2687d337-2b60-4f20-b581-a70807c22cb9': Directory not empty
 find: cannot delete `/var/tmp/foreman-ssh-cmd-faedbb3a-7756-4c96-8a40-a4a2001b5fb3': Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not used any `-type` option, so `find` will remove (`-delete`) everything that is matched by conditions provided (precisely `-mindepth 1  -mtime +5` here), whether it is file or directory (if empty) or anything else.

If you want to remove empty directories only:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -delete
```

Just to note, it is better to have a look at the files to be removed before actually doing the removal, drop the `-delete`:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1-type d -mtime +5
```

---

For the sake of completeness, if you want to search for only files and directories, insert an OR construct in `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 \( -type f -o -type d \) -mtime +5
```

---

If you want to remove the directories that are not empty as well, use `rm` inside the `-exec` action:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 \( -type f -o -type d \) -mtime +5 -exec rm -r {} +
```

Add `-f` with `rm` if needed.

Comment: can we remove the option - -mindepth 1 , and what this option mean ?

Comment: @yael You should not remove that, otherwise the `$PWD` will be matched (current directory: `.`), `-mindepth 1` prevents that.

Comment: see my update the delete option cant remove folder that not empty , how to resolve this

Comment: @yael Check my edits.

Comment: Warning! order on `find` command line is significant! `depth` options **have to be** placed **before** filters (like type of name)!!!

Comment: @F.Hauri I didn't say anything about that. Note that the question you linked to concerns comments in response to an answer, not comments in response to a comment. On Unix.SE we commonly respond to comments with a comment, not just a comment upvote, in particular so that the commenter is notified.

Comment: Oh BTW depth options *aren't* positional, they apply to all tests regardless of their position. `find` warns you if they're not placed first but that's just for readability.